# SQL Help - Find all distinct IDs that are not equal to a value - There are multiple IDs that are the same

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to return the IDs in a table where the IDs do not contain a value in another column. There are multiple IDs in the table that are the same, however the second column contains a different value. I want to return all of the distinct IDs where the second column does not contain a value of 10.

For example my data table looks like:

```
ID | Value
32 |   8
32 |   9
32 |  10
35 |   8
35 |   9
```

As per the table above I want to return all the IDs that do not contain 10, however when I run the following script I am getting back a result that gives me all the values that contain 8 & 9 and only omits 10 when I want just the distinct ID that have no rows that all contain 10  in the Values column.

I am also joining to another table.

```
select distinct table1.ID, table2.Values
from table1
left join table2 on table1.ID=table2.ID
where table2.Values <> 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be a `HAVING`:

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE [Value] WHEN 10 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I think this has worked.

Comment: If it answers the question, please do accept it as the solution, @YuriNator , so that future readers know that the answer was helpful.